# sequence of functions satisfying some conditions.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that {$f_n$} is a sequence of continuous real valued functions on $[0,1]$  satisfying the following properties

> 1).$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},$   $f_n(x)$ is a decreasing sequence .
>
> 2).the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$

let $g_n(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k f_k(x)  \;\;\forall\; x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then

> 1).$g_n (x)$ is a cauchy with respect to the sup norm .
>
> 2).$g_n$ is uniformly convergent.
>
> 3).$g_n$ need not be pointwise convergent.
>
> 4).$\exists M >0 $ such that$ \left |g_n (x)   \right | \leq M, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

the solution i tried

By applying Dirichlet's test  we can see that given series is uniformly convergent

so option 2 is true  and the option 3 is wrong, now i stuck on option 1st and 4th, in option 1st i know about sup norm but don't know how to apply that here.

please help

Thankyou

Comment: Option 2 implies option 1 (uniform convergence pointwise) and option 4 (uniform boundedness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniformly convergent sequences are Cauchy w.r.t sup norm so 1) is true. For 4) note that the limit $g$ is continuous hence bounded. We have $|g_n(x)| \leq |g_n(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)|<1+|g(x)|$ for all $x$ if $n$ is sufficiently large, say $n \geq n_0$. Since $g_n$ is bounded for  each $n <n_0$ we see that 4) is true.

Comment: Thank you sir ,but how uniformly convergent sequence is Cauchy under sup norm?

Comment: $g_n \to g$ uniformly iff given $\epsilon >0$ there exits $n_0$ such that $\|g_n-g\|<\epsilon /2$ for all $n \geq n_0$. By triangle inequality $\|g_n-g_m\| \leq \|g_n-g\|+\|g_m-g\| <\epsilon$ if $m,n \geq n_0$

Comment: once again Thank you sir, even my college teachers never answered that fast. i appreciate sir.